# Spring get open websocket connections

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket

I am using Spring Boot Websocket to enable my Spring Boot 2 microservice to deal with websocket connections.

My config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WsConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler;

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {

        DefaultHandshakeHandler handshakeHandler = new DefaultHandshakeHandler();
        handshakeHandler.setSupportedProtocols(HANDSHAKE_PROTOCOL);

        registry.addHandler(webSocketHandler, WS_HANDLER_PATH + WILDCARD)
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .setHandshakeHandler(handshakeHandler);

    }
}
```

My clients are able to connect to my Service via Websocket. I am implementing `WebSocketHandler` interface to handle messages and log connections.

Now my question: Is there a way to show all current websocket users/sessions?
I was trying to use the SimpUserRegistry:

```
@Configuration
public class UserConfig {
    final private SimpUserRegistry userRegistry = new DefaultSimpUserRegistry();

    @Bean
    public SimpUserRegistry userRegistry() {
        return userRegistry;
    }
}
```

and to show the users via a REST endpoint

```
@RestController
public class WebSocketManager {

    private final SimpUserRegistry userRegistry;

    public WebSocketManager(SimpUserRegistry userRegistry) {
        this.userRegistry = userRegistry;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/users")
    public List<String> getConnectedUsers() {
        userRegistry.getUsers().stream()
                .map(SimpUser::getName)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("Users " + userRegistry.getUsers());
        System.out.println("UsersCount " + userRegistry.getUserCount());
        return this.userRegistry
                .getUsers()
                .stream()
                .map(SimpUser::getName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

But this always gives my an empty list: `[]` even when obviously WS connections are established.

Is this `SimpUserRegistry` working with the Websocket system of Spring which is configured with the `WebSocketConfigurer` and `@EnableWebSocket`? What am I doing wrong? Any tips or alternatives?

Thank you in advance!